# How could I make a google verification box which register people into my web site?

Tags: google-plus, verification

The image describes itself the objetive:

[image]
If someone doesn't understand, I want to create a register box which registers the g+ email into a database with the respective user's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called OAuth. Usually we use an external provider (such as Google, Facebook, Github, etc.) to identify the user, so you don't have to. The user don't have to give you his password, because you use access tokens to request the user's data from the provider's server:

[image: Google OAuth workflow example]

You can read more and find implementations [here](https://oauth.net/2/).

On the image, you probably see the [Google's OAuth2 service](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).